# Getting Group Policy attributes for an OU in C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, msdn, group-policy

I am trying to recreate the following powershell code in c#.  This will return me

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter *| Get-GPInheritance | Where-Object {$_.GPOInheritanceBlocked}
```

The closest thing I can come up with (and it doesn't work) is this:

```
using Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Commands;  
using System.Management.Automation;

GetGPInheritanceCommand inheritance = new GetGPInheritanceCommand();
inheritance.Domain = domain;
inheritance.Target = "ou=brandon,dc=centoso,dc=com";
// I can't figure out where to go from here. I have tried the following:

// The below returns "d__0"
var res = inheritance.Invoke();
Console.WriteLine(res);

// The below attempt just throws an error.
foreach (var res in inheritance.Invoke())
{
     Console.WriteLine(res);
}
```

MSDN is very vague in reference to Group Policy for Active Directory when it comes to C#.